# Typescript button type outside of React?

Tags: html, typescript

Is there a built-in type for button type (outside of React context):

```
type: "button" | "submit" | "reset";
```

Something like

```
HTMLButtonElement['type']
```

(which doesn't exist)

Comment: `HTMLButtonElement['type']` works for me: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAQgrsYB7AdgFXNAvFAEmgWQBl5FUBRAGwgFsIVgBtAclEmYF0AoAeh6gFQAegH4gA

Comment: button=document.querySelector("button");
button.getAttribute("type") and button.type both working